# JavaScript Fade In Not Working Correctly - 2 of 4 divs fade in correctly

Tags: javascript

I just need each div to fade in once, doesn't need to fade out. Only .landing and .about fade in. .images and .contact don't fade in at all, but I can still click the invisible button on the .images div. If you need my CSS for the ids, please let me know. I'm still a JavaScript beginner, so this could be an easy fix.

```
<div class="landing">

  <div class="content" id="fadein"> <!-- "fadein" is for my onload function -->

    <div class="header">
      <h1 style="margin: 0;">Placeholder</h1>
      <h4 style="margin: 0;">Placeholder</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="down">
      <a href="#about">
        <img src="down.png">
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<a id="about"></a>
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="content" id="fadeinclick">

    <h3 style="margin: 0;">Placeholder</h3>
    <h3 style="margin: 0;">Placeholder</h3>
    <h3 style="margin: 0;">Placeholder</h3>
    <h3 style="margin: 0;">Placeholder</h3>

    <div class="down">
      <a href="#images">
        <img src="down.png">
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<a id="images"></a>
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="content" id="fadeinclick"> <!-- first div that won't fade in -->

    <h3>Images</h3>

    <div class="activity">
      <img src="placeholder.png"></img>
      <img src="placeholder.png"></img>
      <img src="placeholder.png"></img>
    </div>

    <div class="down">
      <a href="#contact">
        <img src="down.png">
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<a id="contact"></a>
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="content" id="fadeinclick"> <!-- second div that won't fade in -->

    <h3>Contact</h3>

    <div class="activity">
      <img src="placeholder.png"></img>
      <img src="placeholder.png"></img>
      <img src="placeholder.png"></img>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<!-- Fade scripts -->
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("fadein").style.opacity = 1;
  }
</script>

<script>
  window.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("fadeinclick").style.opacity = 1;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

opacity isn't a child of style, but rather a property. Just do

```
elem.style = "opacity:100%"
```

But keep in mind it won't fade. My advice?

```
var fade = 0
var elem = document.getElementById('imageId')
rate = 1

function step() {
fade = fade + 1
}
function start() {
if (fade < 100) {
step()
setInterval(function() {start}, rate)
};
};
```